# Python 3.4: IndexError: String index out of range. Bruteforce

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, index-error

I am working on a brute-force decryption for Caesar Cipher encrypted messages using a dictionary attack however when scanning for words in my dictionary file it will print the word but then return the error "IndexError: String index out of range". This also occurs when using more than one word. Thanks

```
import csv
global alphabet, space, punctuation, msg, OFFSET, isSolved
alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
space = (" ")
punctuation = (".,!?':+-=£")
OFFSET = 0
isSolved = False
def crack():
    global alphabet, space, punctuation, msg, OFFSET, isSolved
    while not isSolved:
        toScan = str()
        for letter in list(msg):
            for punc in punctuation:
                if letter == punc:
                    toScan += punc
            if letter == space:
                toScan += space   
            for alpha in range(26):
                if letter.lower() in alphabet[alpha]:
                    toScan += str(alphabet.upper()[alpha-int(OFFSET)])
        dictionary = open("dict.csv", "r")
        reader = csv.reader(dictionary)
        for row in dictionary:
            if toScan.lower() in str(row.lower()):
                print(toScan.upper())
            else:
                OFFSET += 1

while True:
    print("[Xiphos Bruteforce.py]")
    print("1) Decrypt a message")
    print("2) Add word to the dictionary")
    print("3) Exit")
    r = input()
    if r == "1":
        msg = input("Please enter the message to crack\n")
        crack()
    if r == "2":
        None
    if r == "3":
        exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that are wrong with your code, but the short answer is this line:

```
toScan += str(alphabet.upper()[alpha-int(OFFSET)])
```

You loop over 26 different values of `alpha` and with each iteration of `while` loop you add +1 to OFFSET, so after 78 iterations, your OFFSET has a value of 78, and so you try to get `25-78=-53` index of `alphabet.upper()` which doesn't exist (remember about negative reverse indexing in Python).

This is the answer to your question, but besides that:

- don't use global variables, they are really useless in this case, to avoid it you can for example pass an argument `msg` to your function as an argument, and initiate rest of it inside the function
- your `while` loop never ends, that's one of the reasons your code fails, you should stop it somewhere with setting `isSolved=True` somewhere
- however, while loop is redundant here, you can use `for offset in range(26)` for the main loop, since anyways you don't want your offset to be bigger than that
- you can get all the alphanumeric values, such as letters from str library which is built in Python
- you also don't close your file anywhere, it's also a mistake, which can be handled by closing the file manually, or performing operations on it in a `with` statement
- you don't have to iterate over `punctuations`, `if letter in punctuations` handles it perfectly

I won't say anything about logic, it's your way of thinking of this problem, thumbs up for putting it in code, but afterwards try to improve the logic and get most of it from as little code as possible.

### Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! I changed the way I was attempting brute-force and i have finally got it working, much appreciated

Comment: Glad to hear that!